# Excel's "Replace Text As You Type" AutoCorrect option stops working at 256-long cells

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013, microsoft-excel-2016, autocorrect

If your "Replace Text As You Type" option is supposed to replace text of length L with another text, then if the cell contains over 255 characters (including L), the "Replace Text As You Type" AutoCorrect option will not work.

Is this a bug? Is there any way to increase that limit?

Comment: Excel is not a word processor. Certain functions stop working with more than 255 characters. You're not the first to comment on this. I'd say its a bug, but Microsoft likely will say its by design.

Comment: @LPChip - It's not a bug, it's a feature. ... :P